# Not able to get Location by GPS : Android

Tags: android, android-location

I am new to android. I am trying to get my location using GPS.
I have included the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Whenever I am trying to get my `Location` from `LocationManager` using `getLastKnownLocation` I am getting null object. Also, GPS is enabled. Here is my code:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location location;
if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
    Log.d("ManualLog", "GPS_DISABLED");
    Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(settingsIntent);
} else {
    Log.d("ManualLog", "GPS_ENABLED");
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running it on emulator or device?
If on emulator, you may need to send GPS data manually to emulator via "emulator control". In eclipse, you can find it Window>Open Perspective>DDMS.

If you are running on device, is it possible your device never received a GPS signal before?

Comment: I am running it on a device and it had GPS signal before.

Answer (score 2):

locationManager.getLastKnownLocation will return null if the GPS has not had time to get a fix yet. Android does not provide a 'give me the location now' method. When the GPS has got a fix, the onLocationChanged() will run. It is **event driven**, you have to be patient and wait for that event. Once onLocationChanged() has run, then getLastKnownLocation() will return a non null value.

Comment: Generally, how much time does it take. I mean, I have been using GPS earlier, using Google Map and other applications. So, it should have got a fix by now. Isn't it?

Comment: It depends on whether you have a clear view of the sky, etc. Are you sure that GoogleMap didn't just get the position from the network? Best thing is to test it, put a Toast call in onLocationChanged() and see how long it takes.

Comment: What is the way to know that GoogleMap takes my location from GPS? Also, I have already requesting for a location update using requestLocationUpdates. However, onLocationChanged takes more than 15 minutes to respond. As I have a service running for it, it somehow timesout

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the last line by:

```
List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
if(!providers.isEmpty()) {
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(0));
} else {
   Log.d("ManualLog", "No provider");
}
```

Comment: It works but provider is Network in this case. I need it from GPS.

Comment: ANd in the list `providers`, do you have GPS? Maybe it's not the first element in the list...

Comment: Yes i have GPS in the list of 'providers' and it is at third element in the list. I changed the code, but still I am getting null.